# How do I make a link to an image return a dynamically updating image?

Tags: image, http, webserver

The title isn’t worded well but I’m not sure how to concisely put it. Basically I want to have an image hosted somewhere that will dynamically update its contents while maintaining the same URL.

As an example, let’s say I embedded “https://example.com/dayofweek.jpg”. If you view this post on the day it was created, it would have an image containing the word Sunday. If you viewed the post tomorrow, the post would remain unedited and the link would be the same, but the image would contain the word Monday (barring things like browser caching).

I know how to get the info I need and how to generate an image, I just need to know how to make this last part happen. Will I need to write and host a simple web server, or is there some other way to accomplish it?